# Which daemon or process updates /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp?

Tags: sensor, real-time, background

Just curious... been exploring the RPi H/W... can't escape my embedded device-driver "down on the bare metal" past... in that vein I noticed the value in ../thermal_zone0/temp is always different from the value returned by `vcgencmd measure_temp`, by a varying delta of 0.6 to 1.8 degC... interesting...

... what other mechanisms are there for monitoring temperatures on the SoC and NIC chip?  Any other chips have thermal issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Values in `/sys/class/thermal` are updated by the [thermal driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/thermal/sysfs-api.txt). Its sources can be found under `linux/drivers/thermal`.

`vcgencmd` talks to a closed-source SoC driver, which apparently takes its temperature value elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks much!  "vcgencmd talks to a closed-source SoC driver..." ah yes, Broadcom, Eben Upton, and their "Binary Blob Alliance"... so sad... SMH.